# sublime text 3 write shape and sticker (,,)

Tags: sublimetext3

just now I get some message in the sublime text that uses some specific shapes like 
, and .
who knows how I can write this everywhere that I want?

what I have:

> Git Gutter? Want to support development?
>
> ⭐ ES6 ⭐
>
> ES6.io/friend/GITGUTTER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a good amount of ways to achieve this. The shapes and stickers are symbols listed under the unicode directory.

You are going to be flooded with a lot of answers, I will share the two ways I know how to do this:

1. Copy the unicode symbol from a [website](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F984/) and paste it like so,
2. Install a sublime plugin called the ***Unicode Completion*** (there will be other plugins, do search for them)

*Note: The unicode for a particular symbol is the same across the world, but how this unicode character gets rendered (the looks) is defined by the software that is being used.*

**To install the plugin Unicode Completion and to use it, do as follows,**

1. Press "**Ctrl + Shift + p**" in sublime
2. Type in ***install*** and choose "***Package Control: Install Package***"
3. Type in ***unicode*** and search for the ***UnicodeCompletion*** package and press enter, you will see at the bottom  most bar in sublime, near the left the progress of installation
4. Once the plugin is installed, press "**Ctrl + Shift + p**" again and type "***unicode completion***"
5. Choose "***Unicode Completion: Unicode Lookup***" from the list of options that comes up
6. You will now see a list of symbols followed by the `/:command:` required to insert that command (you can search that list by typing a symbol's name in the text bar there)
7. For example, type ***heart*** in that text bar and you will see that there a few types of hearts there (*you can press enter there on one and it will be copied to your clipboard and later can be pasted*)
8. So you type `\:` followed by the command for the heart symbol you want up to an extent and press tab key for converting it into a unicode symbol ❤